# Search page shows an empty page with page.tpl.php template

Tags: 7, search

I am setting up a search page in Drupal 7 and when I click on *Search* after entering a keyword, it just shows me an empty page.tpl.php. In other words, it just shows me the page.tpl.php template with no result in it.

Is there a way to fix it? Why is it happening?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should expand your question, and explain how you are setting up a search page. Generally speaking, a search page doesn't use page.tpl.php as template file.

Comment: It is actually surprising for me too. I enabled Search module and `search-result.tpl.php` and `search-results.tpl.php` is in my theme folder; but still it is showing me `page.tpl.php` template. When I remove `page.tpl.php` however, it works perfectly. Any idea why this is happening?